# Strange emails from Cronjob. (No such file or directory)

Tags: cron, debian, sendmail

I'm a fool in linux. So i tried to set up some things on my root.
Well and after time a suspicious cron job started to bomb me. i get about 1 email every 10 minutes saying:

> Cron 
>   test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail &&
>   /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp
>
> /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: line
>   880: /usr/sbin/sendmail-msp: No such
>   file or directory

Does someone know what this could be?

The email is adressed to "root@example.com"....

greetings

Comment: which debian version do you use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution:

apt-get --purge remove sendmail-base sendmail-cf sendmail-doc

This just popped up for me too. I thought that I had removed sendmail when I installed Postfix but these cron jobs started popping up. Removing the sendmail file from /etc/cron.d worked until I restarted the machine, at which point it was regenerated. Removing the packages listed solved the problem once and for all. :-)

Comment: I did exactly as you did. Initially, I only removed the cron entry and when restarted the emails came back flooding my inbox. Only after removing the entire sendemail packages, the emails stopped. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your sendmail package isn't completely installed. Try to find our which package contains sendmail-msp and install this package. You shouldn't receive mail anymore.

Comment: i have postfix installed. dont know anything, i only knew that i can send emails via SMTP (In PHP normal mail() also doensn't work.)

Comment: i just realized that "openfire" comes to top of "top" when i get an email. maybe i should just remove openfire ^^

Answer (score 3):

On my ubuntu system, it's `/etc/cron.d/sendmail`

This seems to be a file left over from when I had sendmail installed: `dlocate -S /etc/cron.d/sendmail` returns nothing...

So I just removed it.

I also found a couple other `sendmail-*` packages removed but not purged.  When I purged them, it all went away. :-/

Comment: Removing the file did seems to work for me, unfortunately it reappeared when I rebooted the server. So instead I edited the file to comment out the cron job, this seems to survive a reboot.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered after I posted above that there were other packages that were removed but not purged. I edited my answer to add that info.

Answer (score 3):

Found it!
Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557127&p=9743741#post9743741

The file /etc/cron.d/sendmail seems to be autogenerated by sendmail.

```
"Sendmail crontab - Call sendmail at various times to do the following:
1) Age queues - move undelivered mail to a slower queue
2) Retry any mail queued by the message submission process
3) run the queues (deliver mail) if a standalone daemon is not desired"
```

So if you go to

```
sudo nano /etc/cron.d/sendmail
```

and comment the line which fires the cron, I think you're done. But that's not the root of the problem.

I think you should go to edit this other file

```
sudo nano /etc/mail/sendmail.conf
```

and scroll down until the "queue" sections, follow the inline documentation and try until you got it :)

Regards!